# JavaScript shuffling deck so no three same suit

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, search

I have a homework assignment, where I create a pack of playing cards, and as a bonus I randomize them. We're supposed to randomize them so that no three cards in a row have the same suit. I have randomized them using the Fisher-Yates Method.

It works most of the time, but there is still a chance that three cards can have the same suit in a row.

How can I run a loop and scan the three cards in a row to see if they are the same suit, so that if it's true, I can run my randomize function again?

Here is my code:

```
var suits = ["Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clovers"];
var faces = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "Kings", "Joker"]
var a = " of "
var deck = [];
var temp = null;

//Looping through arrays, combining faces to each suit
//Faces is length-1 to not insert all jokers
for (i = 0; i < suits.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < faces.length-1; j++) {
    //Looping through each of the suits
    deck.push(faces[j] + a + suits[i])
  }
}
//Inserting 1 joker to the deck
deck.push(faces[13])
console.log(deck)

//Shuffle the deck, using Fisher-Yates shuffle
//Researched from Frank Mitchell: https://www.frankmitchell.org/2015/01/fisher-yates/

for (k = deck.length - 1; k > 0; k -= 1) {
  m = Math.floor(Math.random() * (k + 1))
  temp = deck[k]
  deck[k] = deck[m]
  deck[m] = temp
}

console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^")
console.log("---Shuffling Deck----")
console.log("vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv")
console.log(deck)
```

Notes: So best as what I can guess, and I know it will require more processes is to do a for loop for each suit type (running this search loop four times), then using indexOf(suits[i]), but then how do I compare that to deck[i + 1] and [i + 2]? How do I create the comparison of the suit that I'm looking for, and the suit in the deck?

Also, card elements are named in the Array: "Ace of Diamonds", "5 of Spades"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find it easier to represent each card as an object `{Suit:'Hearts', Face:'Ace'}`. This will let you easily determine which suit a card is without having to do string manipulation. If you have a hard requirement to use strings to represent the cards, you could just use a regular expression to extract the word after `of` in your exapmle.

In terms of looking for 3 of the same suit, you don't need to look for each suit independently. Just look one card at a time and look to see if its suit matches that of `i-1` and `i-2` (while being mindful of the first cards of course).

Comment: So I'm dealing with a requirement to have them as strings. How would I extract the substring after every ' of ' ?

Comment: @as.beaulieu, I think "how do I extract the substring" was answered above. (Use regular expression.) You should try that and ask more specifically about your point of difficulty if you have trouble, probably in a separate more focused question.

Comment: Why don't you process the data as though objects, not strings, and then due to string requirement, just return them as a strings at the end?

Comment: How would I use a regular expression with a variable? I take it I would also use the * symbol to search for a certain substring across a whole string?Would it be something like suit[i]*

Comment: @as.beaulieu For the regular expression in particular I'd ask that in a separate question, but for posterity `"4 of Hearts".replace(/(.*?) of (.*)/,'$2')` returns `"Hearts"`. But using objects for the traversal and only doing strings at the end is probably better since it'll keep you from having to evaluate the regular expression so many times (which can be expensive).